# Angular 6 append value to Observable

Tags: angular, rest, observable

**messenger.component.ts**

```
import { MessengerService } from 'messenger.service';

messages: any =[];

ngOnInit(): void {
    // call logs to http api
    this.messages = this.messengerService.getData();
}

sendMessage(message){
   this.messages.subscribe(data => {
        data.push({
            message_from: 'borrower',
            message: message
        });
       console.log(data);
    });
}
```

> OUTPUT CONSOLE.LOG(data)
>
> ```
> 0: {message_from: "borrower", message: "hi", status: 0, user: 1}
> 1: {message_from: "borrower", message: "test", status: 0, user: 1}
> 2: {message_from: "borrower", message: "yea", status: 0, user: 1}
> 3: {message_from: "borrower", message: "aasd", status: 0, user: 1}
> 4: {message_from: "borrower", message: "aaa", status: 0, user: 1}
> ```

**messenger.service.ts**

```
public getData(): Observable<MessageData[]> {
        return this.http.get<MessageData[]>('API', {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${sessionStorage.getItem('token')}`,
                Accept: 'application/json'
            }
        }).pipe(map(response => response['success']));
    }
```

**messenger.component.html**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let message of messages | async ">
            //template  
 </ng-container>
```

Already able fetch the data from Web server API. I want to add another function that sends data and able to show it as soon it clicks submit. How can do that using Observable, which ables to append to the previous list ?

[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eokM4.png)

I just wanted to show immediately the message after the function click `sendMessage` which will save through API and sync it with the Observable

Comment: Use `Subject()/BehaviorSubject()`.

Comment: How are you sending the message data? What's the name of your service and the name of your Component? What method do you call when you submit from your Component?

Comment: @Jai can you please explain it further ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completely untested, but the idea is that you use a `BehaviourSubject` which holds your new user inputted data. Which will be merged `onSubmit` and send to the `this.messages` using `combineLatest`. While on loading of the component it gets the messages from the service.

```
newMessages = new BehaviourSubject<MessageData[]>([]);

messages: Observable<MessageData[]> = combineLatest(
  this.newMessages,
  this.messengerService.getData()
).pipe(
  map(([added, data]) => data.concat(added))
);

sendMessage(message): void {
  const messages = this.newMessages.getValue();
  messages.push(message);

  this.newMessages.next(messages);
  this.messengerService.addMessage({
    message_from: 'borrower',
    message
  }); // make proper sending logic here
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to add an (static) array item  in an existing 
 Observable<MessageData[]>

Comment: @marjorieasensi No.

Comment: @PierreDuc - how about converting the array to Observable ? Have you check my updated questions ?

Comment: @marjorieasensi my solution immediately updates the array, and also updates the view, without the need to wait for the saving of the message

Answer (score 0):

If I true understand you question you can use this method

```
currentTook = new BehaviorSubject([]);
```

in get request

```
    this.currentTook.next(sendData);
```

and in another component you can input this

```
@Input() currentTook: Observable<any>;

this.currentTook.subscribe(data => {
         console.log(data);

     });
```